# D3.js plot not rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3.js is quite hard to get your head around. Especially with little experience of JavaScript, of course.

I am trying to recycle the `marvel.html` graph, available [here](https://github.com/jrladd/marvel_network/blob/master/marvel.html), which uses d3.js v4.0. This code works on [this bl.ocks page](https://bl.ocks.org/jrladd/c76799aa63efd7176bd9006f403e854d), but does not render on any of my Mac and Linux machines.

I have run basic bl.ocks examples on these machines, and they render fine. Any friendly soul, who could take the time to help me out in understanding why the `marvel.html` (with the entire library cloned) won't run on any of my machines? Seeing that the data is in the json file, and that d3.js is called via https and not a local file, I think it should work locally if it works on bl.ocks... Thanks!

Comment: Where is your JSON data file? Is it on your local file system?

Comment: Yes, it is the same file structure as https://github.com/jrladd/marvel_network

Comment: You need to set up a local server, you cannot just access the file system. Have a look at the question I closed this as being a duplicate of.